# Is there any way to mapping a AllowHtml attribute with fluent API? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, attributes, ef-fluent-api

```
public class Body 
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to mapping with fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a good question. I have similar problem too. I have a library with POCO classes for my Data Layer. [AllowHtml] attribute requires referencing System.Web.MVC which is supposed to be used in Presentation (UI) Layer. Is there some way how to decorate some property with [AllowHtml] attribute outside a Data Layer Class? I would like to avoid using [ValidateInput(false)] in my controller's Actions.

(I know, that Data Layer classes should not be used in UI Layer, but some of them are useable.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [AllowHtml] attribute to a view model and use that view model in the controller and view as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886670/318807)