# how to use allowhtml attribute for an action in mvc5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, insert, action

I am developing an MVC 5 project and I want to use [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) for input data. This data is saved as HTML, but when I try to display it, I get an error.
[See code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqdqW.png)

Answer (score 16):

You can apply `AllowHtml` attribute to the property which holds the markup in your view model class.

```
public class CreatePost
{
  public string PostTitle {set;get;}
  [AllowHtml]
  public string PostContent { set;get;}
}
```

And use this view model in your HttpPost action method and everything will work fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreatePost viewModel)
{
  // Check viewModel.PostContent property
  // to do  : Return something
}
```

Now just make sure you are using this property to build the text area to be used with CKEditor

```
@model CreatePost
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.PostTitle)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(s=>s.PostContent)
    <input type="submit" />
}
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
       CKEDITOR.replace('Message');
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute the action (post) in the controller that you want to allow HTML for:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostForm(Model model)
{
 //
}
```

Comment: I used this but I got the same Error again

Comment: Can you try [ValidateInput(false)] instead of  [AllowHtml] @javad

Comment: ok.every this were ok.but when I show to about view it shows only below      <h2 style="font-style:italic;"><strong>sddvsdsdvsd</strong></h2> <p><strong>gsgsdsd</strong></p>

Comment: It's better to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886670/15054795) approach as this way only that property has a vulnerability, vs here that all the properties have vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute, first you have to add the attribute `requestValidationMode="2.0"` in your httpRuntime tag in the site's Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

That worked for me.